# What's the command of call operator &?

Tags: powershell

I used `ls alias:` and tried to find `&`. However, `&` is not in the output. What's `&`? Is it the combination of [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) and [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6)?

Are there any other operators which don't have a cmdlet in PowerShell?

Comment: It's an operator, thus a part of the language syntax like `+`.

Comment: Operators != aliases. Lachie White has answered about `&`. As for the rest of them, there are too many to list. Read the help-files listed here `Get-Help *operators*`

Comment: @FrodeF. executing `Get-Help *operators*` showed nothing.

Comment: The asterisks were by design. You can wildcard search with get-help for topics. At least in newer PS versions. Try update-help to make sure you have downloaded all help files

Comment: Testet wildcard search in PS2.0 now and it works (at least with `PowerShell.exe -version 2`), so it probably returned nothing because you hadn't downloaded the help-files with `update-help`. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The call operator `&` allows you to execute a command, script or function.

Many times you can execute a command by just typing its name, but this will only run if the command is in the environment path. Also if the command (or the path) contains a space then this will fail. Surrounding a command with quotes will make PowerShell treat it as a string, so in addition to quotes, use the `&` call operator to force PowerShell to treat the string as a command to be executed.

[PowerShell Call Operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html)

I am not sure of all the operators that are in PowerShell, but another really useful one is `--%`, used to stop parsing.

The stop-parsing symbol `--%`, introduced in PowerShell 3.0, directs PowerShell to refrain from interpreting any further input on the line as PowerShell commands or expressions.

[PowerShell Stop Parsing Operator](https://ss64.com/ps/stop-parsing.html)

Building on the comments that have been made:

```
Get-Help About_Operators
```

It will show you the best overview of all operator types and abstract ones like the Call and Stop Parsing Operators.

Comment: Here's the online version of about operators https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators

Comment: The online version can also be accessed by using 
`Get-Help About_Operators -Online`

Answer (score 4):

Some other uses for the call operator, not well documented:

```
# Get and set a variable in a module scope with the call operator 
# get module object
$m = get-module counter

& $m Get-Variable count
& $m Set-Variable count 33

# see module function definition
& $m Get-Item function:Get-Count

# run a cmdlet with a commandinfo object and the call operator
$d = get-command get-date
& $d
```

You can think of `& { }` as an anonymous function.

```
1..5 | & { process{$_ * 2} }
```

Another really useful operator is the subexpression operator.  $( )  It's not just for inside strings.  You can combine two statements and make them act as one.

```
$(echo hi; echo there) | measure
```

If and Foreach statements can go inside them too.  You couldn't normally pipe from foreach ().  So anywhere you could put an expression or pipeline, with $() you can put any statement or group of statements.

```
$(foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i;sleep 1 } ) | Out-Gridview
```

Although, I like streaming from foreach with the call operator (or function), so I don't have to wait.

```
 & {foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i;sleep 1 } } | Out-GridView
```

Comment: I didn't know there were these kinds of useful behaviors. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Have a good day.

Comment: @SmartHumanism Thanks.  I got it from the book Windows Powershell In Action.

Comment: Thank you for your politeness and for sharing the source you learned from.

If I may ask you a bit, `& {foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i;sleep 1 } }` seems to work the same way `% {foreach ($i in 1..10) { $i;sleep 1 } }`. What would be the difference between the `&` operator and the `%` operator, here?

Comment: @SmartHumanism They don't really compare.  % is foreach-object, which you can pipe from compared to the other foreach ().

Comment: I tested and it seems that `%` can be used in a similar way as `&`. The difference seems to be the scope, if you run `& {$temp = 3}` then, when you type $temp there shows no outcome, whereas, in the case of `% {$temp = 3}` you can get `$temp`'s value in the current PowerShell scope.