# Powershell: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument “test”

Tags: powershell, cmd, parameters

I'm trying to execute the following command via command line

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  Send-MailMessage -from "mail.me" -to "mail.me" -Subject "PS test !" -Body "Hi this is a power shell mail test" -SmtpServer "mail.domain.com"
```

But I'm getting the following error :

> Send-MailMessage: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument  « test ».
> Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 17
>
> - Send-MailMessage <<<<  -from mail.me -to mail.me -Subject PS test ! -Body Hi this is a power shell mail test -SmtpServer mail.domain.com
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell
>   .Commands.SendMailMessage

The problem is that the same command works well when directly executed in Power Shell, but without the path.

What could be the problem generating this exception ?

Comment: Isn't `Send-MailMessage` a PowerShell version 2 cmdlet?

Comment: I made sure it's the same path the Power Shell console is pointing to ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positional Parameter error in powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39407004/positional-parameter-error-in-powershell-script)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-command`and braces. Currently, you are launching powershell and passing it multiple arguments instead of asking it to execute your code.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -command "& {Send-MailMessage -from "mail.me" -to "mail.me" -Subject "PS test !" -Body "Hi this is a power shell mail test" -SmtpServer "mail.domain.com"}"
```

I'm getting errors for the some of values you have set (characters that need to be escaped, invalid emails etc), so replaced and got this to run:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  -Command "& {Send-MailMessage -From test@test.com -To othertest@test.com -Subject "whatevs" -SmtpServer "localhost" -Body "whatevs"}"
```

Comment: I tried this and got ( Send-MailMessage -from mail.me -to mail.me -Subject PS test ! -Body Hi this is a power shell mail test -SmtpServer mail.domain.com ) in output , without the parameters' double quotes, and the command didn't execute

Comment: I got it to work by adding the ( "& ) to the begining and replacing the double quotes by singles quotes, what & is useful for here ?

Comment: @mounaim glad to hear it's working. `&` is the call operator - [see this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382951/whats-the-command-of-call-operator). The [ss64 link](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) in the accepted answer is also useful - I would recommend script blocks as in their example to avoid issues with multiple commands down the line.

Comment: gms0ulman'0 Thank  you so much, I've been struggling with this to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape double quotes in your command. Otherwise command processor strips it, and your "test" appears as parameter to `Send-MailMessage`.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe  Send-MailMessage -from "mail.me" -to "mail.me" -Subject \"PS test !\" -Body \"Hi this is a power shell mail test\" -SmtpServer "mail.domain.com"
```